Lee Introduction to Smooth Manifolds Problem 6-11

$\textbf{Problem 6-11.}$ Suppose $F:M\to N$ and $G:N\to P$ are smooth maps, and $G$ is transverse to an embedded submanifold $X\subseteq P$. Show that $F$ is transverse to the submanifold $G^{-1}(X)$ if and only if $G\circ F$ is transverse to $X$.


$\textbf{Problem 6-10.}$ Suppose $F:N\to M$ is a smooth map that is transverse to an embedded submanifold $X\subseteq M$, and let $W=F^{-1}(X)$. For each $p\in W$, show that $T_pW=(dF_p)^{-1}(T_{F(p)}X)$. Conclude that if two embedded submanifolds $X,X'\subseteq M$ intersect transversely, then $T_p(X\cap X')=T_pX\cap T_pX'$ for every $x\in X\cap X'$.

The forward direction was straight forward; I used the same steps as in the proof of Theorem 6.35. However, for the reverse direction, I was struggling because I could not repeat the same thing. This is my attempt so far:
Let $p\in (G\circ F)^{-1}(X)$, $r=F(p)\in G^{-1}(X)$, and $q=G(r)\in X$. We want to show that
$$T_rG^{-1}(X)+dF_p(T_pM)=T_rN.$$
By transversality, we have
$$T_qX+dG_r(T_rN)=T_qP,$$
$$T_qX+d(G\circ F)_p(T_pM)=T_qP.$$
By the previous problem,
$$T_rG^{-1}(X)=(dG_r)^{-1}(T_qX),$$
$$T_p(G\circ F)^{-1}(X)=(d(G\circ F)_p)^{-1}(T_qX).$$
However, I am stuck here and not sure what to do. I tried doing "system of equation" using these four equations, but it did not work out.

Let $w\in T_rN$. Then $dG_r(w)\in T_qX$, so
$$dG_r(w)=y+dG_r(dF_p(v))$$
for some $y\in T_qX$ and $v\in T_pM$. Since $dG_r(w-dF_p(v))=y\in T_qX$, we have $w-dF_p(v)\in (dG_r)^{-1}(T_qX)=T_rG^{-1}(X).$ Hence, $w-dF_p(v)=z$ for some $z\in T_rG^{-1}(X)$. In particular,
$$w=z+dF_p(v),$$
which completes the proof.
